# Manually caching HTML pages in Django CMS

Tags: django, caching, django-cms

I'm trying o build an addon for Django CMS that would save a static copy of a site on disk. I have set up the addon and I have a button on the toolbar that triggers a view that goes through all the pages, renders them and saves them.

The general setup seems to work fine, but when I check the static HTML files created, they are missing the content of the plugins in each page.

My approach was to reuse the Django CMS details view, which is the one used to render the pages as a response to the browser's HTTP requests. I suspect the problem might have something to do with the request object passed to it, since the one I have available in my view is actually the admin page request, not the one I want to render. But I have tried to overwrite some of its values, I have also checked Django CMS GitHub to see how the request was used but I still can't manage to make the plugin's content show up.

This is my view function:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from cms.views import details
from cms.models.pagemodel import Page

def create_html_files(request):
    cms_pages = Page.objects.filter(publication_date__isnull=False)
    request.user = AnonymousUser()
    done = []
    for page in cms_pages:
        languages = page.get_languages()
        for language in languages:
            url = page.get_public_url(language)
            if url not in done:
                slug = page.get_slug()
                done.append(url)
                path = get_path(url)  # Returns the path of the page
                request.path = path
                request.path_info = path
                request.current_page = page
                request.toolbar.show_toolbar = False
                if page.is_home:
                    template = details(request, '')
                else:
                    template = details(request, slug)
                content = ''
                if hasattr(template, 'render'):
                    content = template.render().content
                else:
                    content = template.content

                content = content.decode("utf-8")

                with open(path, 'w') as file:
                    file.write(content)
```

And it produces the appropriate files but without content. This is the page rendered normally with Django CMS. IT shows some text content.

[image: A sample page rendered live with Django CMS.]

And this is the HTML page produced with my view. The text content is not there, but the rendered page is "correct" (the menu highlights the correct page).

[image: The same page rendered manually.]

I have tried everything I could think of, but the content is still not showing. I'm hoping someone has a simple fix I just didn't think of.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
Using the admin user instead of the AnonymousUser (commenting the line above) does render content, but:

- It does not make any sense. When I log out and see the live site, I can see the content just fine. When I'm logged out I am using the AnonymousUser, so it does not make sense that I need to use the Admin user to render the static files.
- The content that appears is the same in every page, which means the using the Admin user just gives me some additional privileges that lets me access some unpublished content, but it is not the content of the current page. The problem seems to be with identifying the proper page content to draw, nothing to do with the user.
- If I use the Admin user, I see pages on the main menu which are not meant to be public (unpublished pages). This is definitely a no go.

I modified the original Django CMS source code in my current virtual environment to log every single attribute of the request object passed on to the details() view in the two situations (when I try to render them to a static file and when I visit the same page live). I compared both outputs and noticed some differences, but overriding them still does not show the content.

Here's the new view with all the things I have tried to override:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from cms.views import details
from cms.models.pagemodel import Page

def create_html_files(request):
    cms_pages = Page.objects.filter(publication_date__isnull=False)
    request.user = AnonymousUser()
    request._cached_user = request.user
    request._read_started = False
    # This one is very ugly, but in my desperation I simply copied the entire headers from the live request
    request.headers = {'Content-Length': '', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Host': 'localhost:8081', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0', 'Sec-Ch-Ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"', 'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile': '?0', 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9', 'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin', 'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate', 'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1', 'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document', 'Referer': 'http://localhost:8081/en/', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ca;q=0.8,es;q=0.7', 'Cookie': 'django_language=en; _ga=GA1.1.1893957538.1621685583; sessionid_obres=ofe55t22ngs2b7m9xn4zoc2arop6ejlf; discovery=false; csrftoken=6ya4aflnaswZRvuCoSW2FALmBtgrrElxXfsbEf3TjMVgeX8xOMC6WjuNRvNWkXes'}
    del request.cms_latest_entry
    request.COOKIES.pop('sessionid')
    done = []
    for page in cms_pages:
        languages = page.get_languages()
        for language in languages:
            url = page.get_public_url(language)
            if url not in done:
                slug = page.get_slug()
                done.append(url)
                path = get_path(url)  # Returns the path of the page
                request.path = f"/{path}/"
                request.path_info = request.path
                request.META['PATH_INFO'] = request.path
                request.current_page = page
                request.toolbar.show_toolbar = False
                request._read_started = False
                if page.is_home:
                    template = details(request, '')
                else:
                    template = details(request, slug)
                content = ''
                if hasattr(template, 'render'):
                    content = template.render().content
                else:
                    content = template.content

                content = content.decode("utf-8")

                with open(path, 'w') as file:
                    file.write(content)
```

I also checked [the details() view](https://github.com/django-cms/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/views.py#L38) to try to understand how it uses the request object, but I can't see anything that could produce this result.

Comment: have you checked with a real user rather than `AnonymousUser`? comment `request.user = AnonymousUser()` OR please check with a valid user present in the request.

Comment: @AchuthVarghese I did that because I assumed using the AnonymousUser would be the appropriate, as that is the standard user when you are not logged in, and that is what I wanted. But you are right, removing that line (using the admin user as it comes from the original request) does render the plugin contents. Now I have the same content in every page, but I think that is a different matter. If you post it as an answer I'll give you the bounty (I have 24h to do it). Thank you!

Comment: Well, it definitely did not do the trick. If I use the admin user I get some content, but always the same, it is not the page content. I also get access to some unpublished pages, which is definitely not good. The problem must be somewhere else, I suspect the request object.